# Parsing nested json list to model fails flutter

Tags: flutter

I have search screen where i can serach text it will returns data like json below,but when i try to parse data it's not working i am getting data upto this line of code`var data = menu_list[i];`,but when i pass data to model,it's not quite working,any idea what went wrong

**Retrieve json from api function**

```
Future<String> GetSearchdata(String search_text) async {
    ProgressDialog dialog = CustomDialogs().showLoadingProgressDialog(context);
    
      var response = await http.post(Urls.SEARCH_ALL,
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": token},
          body: json.encode({"searchText": search_text, "language": "english"}));
      
      Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
      var status = value['status'];
      var msg_response = value['message'];
      
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
        
            if (status == true) {
              var menu_list = value['doc'];
              if(menu_list.length>0)
                {
                  for (int i = 0; i < menu_list.length; i++) {
                    var data = menu_list[i];
                    _searchResult.add(SearchModel.fromJson(data));
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    print("UI Updated");
                  });
                }
              else{
                final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("No data available"));
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
              }

            } else {
              final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg_response));
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
            }
        
        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg_response));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      }
```

**Model**

```
class SearchModel {
  String id = "";
  String name = "";
  String category_name = "";

  SearchModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.category_name,
  });

  SearchModel.fromJson(json)
      : id = json['_id'].toString(),
        name = json['registrations']['name'].toString(),
        category_name =json['category']['name'].toString();
}
```

**Json**

```
{
    "status":true,
    "doc":{
        "registrations":[
            {
                "_id":"5f44b5aafc77a977e88f558c",
                "name":"test shop",
                "category":[
                    {
                        "name":"/Furnitue Shop"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id":"5f44bd1b52977b4d1411f281",
                "name":"test1",
                "category":[
                    {
                        "name":"/Painting"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code below :

**Model**

```
class SearchModel {
  String id = "";
  String name = "";
  String category_name = "";

  SearchModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.category_name,
  });

  SearchModel.fromJson(json)
      : id = json['_id'].toString(),
        name = json['name'].toString(),
        category_name = json['category'][0]['name'].toString();
}
```

**Retrieve json**

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
        
            if (status == true) {
              var menu_list = value['doc']["registrations"];
              if(menu_list.length>0)
                {
                  final List<SearchModel> listFromJson = menu_list.map<SearchModel>((item) => SearchModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
                  setState(() {
                    _searchResult = listFromJson;
                    print("UI Updated");
                  });
                }
              else{
                final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("No data available"));
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
              }

            } else {
              final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg_response));
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
            }
        
        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg_response));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
```

Comment: the data may more like way more,does this work with what i am trying to do,code is confusing @Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: @MorbiusBlack yes absolutely, you can test it!

Comment: how, can you do this with my code, @Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: still same no change @Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: @MorbiusBlack Is there an error on the log? Are you sure you've changed `json ['category'] ['name']. toString ();` to `json ['category'] [0] ['name']. toString ();`

Comment: yes,there is no error,it just stopped  at line `final List<SearchModel> _searchResults = menu_list.map<SearchModel>((item) => SearchModel.fromJson(item)).toList();`
` also have this error on setState `Undefined name '_searchResults'.`@Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: @MorbiusBlack Check again my edit in the `setState`

Comment: yes,there is no error,it just stopped at line `final List<SearchModel> _searchResults = menu_list.map<SearchModel>((item) => SearchModel.fromJson(item)).toList();` also have this error on setState `Undefined name '_searchResults'.`@Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: @MorbiusBlack What is the type of _searchResult? I just changed the name of the variable `_searchResults`  to `listFromJson` and doing a `setState`. Please check again. 
I tested this code locally and it works for me anyway.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake,it's working now @Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona

Comment: @MorbiusBlack Great :) if the answer helped you, consider upvoting and accepting it as the answer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220434/discussion-between-morbius-black-and-lapa-ny-aina-tanjona).

Answer (score 0):

Few discoveries:

1.

```
var menu_list = value['doc'];
```

This should not be

```
var menu_list = value['doc']['registrations'];
```

instead? The `registrations` is your list, not the `doc`.

2.
After you access the right element, then your model should look like this:

```
    SearchModel.fromJson(json): 
    id = json['_id'].toString(),
    name = json['name'].toString(),
    category_name =json['category']['name'].toString();
```

3. 

Do note, that your `category` is list again (I don't know if it is intended), but if it is, then first you need to get each element from you category list and get the name of those.
Or you need something like this, if you have only 1 element there:

```
category_name =json['category'][0]['name'].toString();
```